# how to remove duplicate values of two different tables with only two columns in common?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have two tables with only  two columns in common that I want to compare to each other and remove duplicate of the common columns

for example TABLE A has 4 columns and table B has 6 columns , I want to get the records of table A , BUT  without the records where the rows matches ( when the values of the two common columns matches )

for example in the common two columns in  tabe A there is code=x , Nature =y and in table B there is also code=x , Nature =y , so this record should be removed when I fetch the table A records ...  I'm using visual studio c# and I didn't know what query to do to fetch these recrods ,any help please

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Please be careful not to misuse tags. The `[visual-studio]` tag is only for questions about the Visual Studio application, not code that you happen to author with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are searching for the NOT IN operator:

```
select table_a.* 
from table_a
where table_a.code NOT IN (select code from table_b)
```

You can test [here](https://sqliteonline.com/) with the following code to create and populate tables:

```
create table table_a (code int, Nature int)
create table table_b (code int, Nature int)

insert into table_a values (1, 10)
insert into table_a values (2, 20)
insert into table_a values (3, 30)

insert into table_b values (2, 20)
insert into table_b values (4, 40)
```

Comment: If `code` is nullable this can return incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

A few methods (I'm assuming SQL Server here since you're using VS and C#):

Use EXCEPT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

```
SELECT
   a.Code,
   a.Nature
FROM dbo.TableA a

EXCEPT

SELECT 
   b.Code,
   b.Nature
FROM dbo.TableB b
```

Alternatively, you can LEFT JOIN TableB where the result is NULL:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b
   ON b.Code = a.Code
   AND b.Nature = a.Nature
WHERE b.Code IS NULL;
```

Comment: These handle nulls differently. `EXCEPT` will consider nulls to be equal to each other, `=` will not. `NOT EXISTS` is another method also.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the NOT EXISTS was the one I was looking for